# Crear 2 o más punteros en una linea

Tags: c++, variables, punteros

Sé que es una pregunta muy corta, pero tengo la duda al inicializar punteros.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int *p1,*p2;

    return 0;
}
```

**¿Es correcto crear 2 punteros así?**

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int *p1,p2;

    return 0;
}
```

**o ¿tiene que ser así?**

Comment: En el segundo ejemplo p2 es un entero (y no un puntero a un entero).

Comment: ¿ Has probado a compilar tus 2 opciones ? ¿ Has obtenido algún error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ¿Es correcto crear 2 punteros así?

Correcto sí, recomendable, no.

Es correcto porque no incumple ninguna regla del lenguaje y, en consecuencia, el compilador sabe generar el binario correspondiente.

Sin embargo, no es recomendable ya que no has inicializado ninguno de esos punteros. Lo suyo sería hacer algo tal que:

```
int *p1 = nullptr, *p2 = nullptr;
```

Si suele ser altamente recomendable la inicialización de todas las variables, con los punteros suele ser prácticamente imprescindible para que nuestro programa funcione.

El problema de los punteros es que no almacenan valores al uso sino direcciones de memoria, entonces mientras que encontrar una variable con un valor tal que `3453453534` suele ser síntoma de una variable sin inicializar... con los punteros no queda suele quedar tan claro.

> ¿tiene que ser así?

En el segundo ejemplo no has declarado dos punteros sino un puntero y una variable de tipo entero.

Es facil de verificar:

```
int *p1, p2;
p1 = p2;
```

Estas dos líneas generan el siguiente error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'
```

Es decir, `p2` **no es un puntero**